# I need to show that functional series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+x^2}}{n^2+e^x}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have a function sequence $$f_n(x) = \frac{\sqrt{n+x^2}}{n^2+e^x},\quad x \in \mathbb{R} $$

I define a function series $$F(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n(x), \quad  F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

I neet to show:
$1)$ that $F$ is differentiable.
$2)$ that $\lim_{x \to 0}F = g$ is exists(over) and if exists that $g > \frac{3}{4}$

$1)$ So I think that
$$f_n'(x) = \frac{x}{(n^2+e^x)\sqrt{n+x^2}} - \frac{e^x\sqrt{n+x^2}}{(n^2+e^x)^2}$$
and if I show that $f_n'(x)$ is uniform convergence, then I have that F is differentiable($f_n$ is pointwise convergence), but I don't now how to show it.
2) As for the second, I don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

All the functions being summed are positive, and

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+x^2}}{n^2+e^x}\le\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{n^2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{n^{3/2}}\implies \text{ Since the positive series}\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt2}{n^{3/2}}\;\;\text{converges,}$$

Weierstrass M-test gives us absolute and uniform convergence in compact subsets of the original series for $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ .

Also observe that for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ :

$$f'_n(x)=\frac{\frac x{\sqrt{n+x^2}}(n^2+e^x)-e^x\sqrt{n+x^2}}{(n^2+e^x)^2}=\frac{xn^2+(x-n-x^2)e^x}{\sqrt{n+x^2}\,(n^2+e^x)^2}$$

Show that also the series of the above derivatives converges absolutely and uniformly and thus the limit function is differentiable and its derivative is the series sum of the derivatives.

Comment: but for which $?$ $f_n'(x) \leq ?$ is true?

Comment: @A.Rokinsky For all of them, as far as I can see:$$\left|\frac{xn^2+(x-n-x^2)e^x}{\sqrt{n+x^2}\,(n^2+e^x)^2}\right|\le\frac{|x|n^2}{\sqrt n\,n^4}\ldots...$$